# Looking for VOIP hardphone suggestions

Tags: voip

I recently had a couple of Grandstream GXP2000 fail on me, and I am looking to replace them with something (hopefully) a little heartier.

I don't need anything too fancy, but the replacement should be a desk phone, with some basic features like speaker phone, and speed dial.  (I imagine these are pretty standard features, but maybe its worth mentioning.)

What I liked about the GXP2000 phones was that they were cheap.  I guess it goes to show you that you get what you pay for, but cost is always a factor.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @lexu, why do you think this belongs on SU?  This is related to administering a VOIP system.  I'm pretty sure that falls under SF jurisdiction, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had great luck with Polycom phones. I've used the [IP450](http://www.polycom.com/products/voice/desktop_solutions/soundpoint/desk_phones/soundpoint_ip450.html) extensively in conjunction with our asterisk server, and have never had a single problem. I've also used the [IP4000](http://www.polycom.com/products/voice/conferencing_solutions/conference_phones/soundstation/soundstation_ip4000.html) conference phone in the past, and it's performed very well.

If you're looking for something a bit cheaper, try the Linksys (I guess it's Cisco now officially) [SPA-941](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10038/index.html). I have a dozen or so of these deployed and they're rock-solid. They don't have the solid physical feel that the polycoms do, but the functionality is solid.

Comment: The Polycom unsurprisingly has the best speaker phone of all the Hard SIP phones I've tested.

Comment: We've been using Polycom phones (IP430 and IP4000) here for the past couple of years and they've all worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can find a good price for them. The Snom phones are pretty good, mass deployment support, http admin interface and a whole bunch of little touches. Things like SIP logs on the phone and packet capturing if you really need to get in deep when trouble shooting.

I've used both the 820 and the various 3x0 varieties.

Answer (score 1):

I've also been happy with Polycom. The SoundPoint IP 321/331 is good for a 2-line phone, and the SoundPoint IP 450 for 3 lines. Both are reasonably priced and will last a long time.

Answer (score 0):

We've used snom for years and they are very good. One nice feature is that they also support Microsoft Office Communications if you ever need to go there in the future!